# Insert a image in imageview with url into sqlite DB without BLOB

Tags: database, image, url, imageview, blob

I need to insert an image into a imageview with url into sqlite DB without using the BLOB, is possible??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I am not aware of any way to save images in SQLite without using BLOBs, and BLOBs of images can be too large for the server to handle smoothly. But I won't claim to have thorough experience with SQLite, so there's a good chance I'm missing something.

Depending on what other resources are at your disposal, one solution would be to just store the url for the image in a TEXT type, but save the image in some other file system. Then when you want to display the image, query the database to get the address (plus whatever other relevant info), isolate it from the results, and query the file system for the image. Implementing this pattern will really depend on the environment your system will be working in; if it's an Android device, you can probably just refer to the filepath it started at, or save it to a dedicated folder; if it's a web interface, the images would most easily be saved as a sub-folder next to the web page(s) that use the images.